# How can flexbox be used to layout Views in two rows and and unknown amount of columns in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am receiving an unknown amount of data(images) from an API endpoint and I want to use flexbox to display the images in 2 rows and an unknown amount of columns depending on the amount of data. How is it done?

```
const [artistes, setArtiste] = useState(null);
```

```
        //get request to endpoint
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/museb/artist/',{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonResponse => 
            setArtiste(jsonResponse)
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .finally(setLoading(false));


        
    }, [])
```

This is where I'm rendering the data

```
                    <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                        {artistes.map((artiste, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Musicplayer")} style={styles.musiccontentsmall}>
                    <Image source={{uri: "http://localhost:8000"+artiste.image}} style={styles.smallimage}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>))}
                    </View>
                    )}
```

**"flexDireciton: row" will put all the content in a single row, but I want it to be in two rows**

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two options.

The first one is answering your specific question using flexbox only:
The trick here is using the wrap style, combining the width size, so with 50% we use two columns or 33% we use three.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
  {artistes.map((artiste, index) => (
    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Musicplayer")} style={[styles.musiccontentsma, { width:"50%" }]}>
    <Image source={{uri: "http://localhost:8000"+artiste.image}} style={styles.smallimag}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
</View>
```

The second option and the best one in terms of performance (because you are using images):

```
<FlatList
  data={artistes}
  numColumns={2}
  renderItem={({ item }) => this._renderItem(item)}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>

_renderItem = item => {
  return (
    <View styles={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
      {...}
    </View>
  )
}
```